# Phalcon Volt adding variable name to input

Tags: phalcon, volt

Ok so this is my code:

```
{%for language in languages %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ language.getLanguage() }}">{{ language.getLanguage() }}</label>
        {{ text_area('{{ language.getLanguage() }}', 'size' : 30, 'class' : 'form-control form-filter input-sm') }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

It works fine on the label but inside the text_area function, it is just displaying `language.getLanguage()` as text and not echoing the value of it. Is there a way to escape out of that function that displays the input to echo the language name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{{ }}` is like doing an `echo`. So in your example you are doing echo echo :)

Try like this:

```
{{ text_area(language.getLanguage(), 'size' : 30, 'class' : 'form-control form-filter input-sm') }}
```

Just a tip: not sure what you are doing inside the `language.getLanguage()` method, but you are calling it 3 times. This leads to unnecessary operations, this can be a huge problem, especially in cases of DB Queries inside the method. **Just assign it to a variable.**

```
{% set lang = language.getLanguage() %}
```